# Access 2010: How to correlate two fields in the same table?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a database in access 2010.

A have a table that has some fields. Three of these are "input", "output" and "date".
A have also a total quantity query.

I want to sum all the "input" values that have the same "date" and I also want to sum all he "output" that have the same "date".

I want my query to find the deduction result ("input" - "output" that have the same "date").

My question is how to correlate different insertions that have the same "date" value.

Any help please?

EDITED:

```
input     output      date
  3         0         2/5/2012
  4         0         8/5/2012
  0         2         2/5/2012
  0         1         8/5/2012
```

I want my query to show

```
available stock     date
   (3-2=) 1       2/5/2012
   (4-1=) 3       8/5/2012
```

EDITED v2:

My sql code is

```
 SELECT SUM(warehouse.in_quant)-SUM(warehouse.out_quant) AS SUM, 
 drugs.active_substance, drugs.strength, drugs.strength_type, drugs.dosage_form, 
 warehouse.available_stock, drugs.minimum_quantity, IIf([warehouse]![available_stock]
 [drugs]![minimum_quantity],"YES!","No") AS DiplayText, warehouse.curr_date
 FROM drugs INNER JOIN warehouse ON drugs.ID = warehouse.drug_id;
```

I get this message:

You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "active_substance" as part of an aggregate function.

When i remove the SUM(warehouse.in_quant)-SUM(warehouse.out_quant) AS SUM it works fine.

Comment: GROUP BY every field that you are not summing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the query design window, add the relevant tables, drag the fields that you want to match from one table to the next. Test. If it is not what you want, post the sql back here with sample data and an explanation of the problem.

```
SELECT i.Input-o.Output As Stock, i.Date
FROM (SELECT Input FROM Table
      WHERE Input > 0) i
LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT Output FROM Table
      WHERE Output > 0) o
ON i.Date = o.Date
```

You will probably need something more complicated, but this should be a start, hopefully.

Re comments

```
SELECT drugs.active_substance, 
       drugs.strength, 
       drugs.strength_type, 
       drugs.dosage_form, 
       warehouse.available_stock, 
       drugs.minimum_quantity, 
       warehouse.curr_date,
       SUM(warehouse.in_quant)-SUM(warehouse.out_quant) AS SUMQty
FROM drugs 
INNER JOIN warehouse ON drugs.ID = warehouse.drug_id
GROUP BY drugs.active_substance, 
       drugs.strength, 
       drugs.strength_type, 
       drugs.dosage_form, 
       warehouse.available_stock, 
       drugs.minimum_quantity, 
       warehouse.curr_date
```

Comment: The fields are in the same table.

Comment: You can add the same table twice.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your asking but to sum values by a date you should use the group by clause

```
SELECT SUM(input) - SUM(output) as 'Input - Output', date 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY date
```

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71450) is an example of it what I think your trying to do.

Comment: This is what i want but i have a problem. See above please.